# Can I use systemd resource management to deny port only outside containers

Tags: systemd, fedora, container, podman, ebpf

On an up-to-date fedora 39, I have set up podman for rootless containers and I limit the ports a user may bind to by creating
/etc/systemd/system/user-1000.slice.d/user-resources.conf
with

```
[Slice]
SocketBindAllow   = 12345
SocketBindDeny    = any
```

Now as expected, the user cannot bind to port 20202 for example:

```
$ nc -4 -lp 20202
Ncat: bind to 0.0.0.0:20202: Operation not permitted. QUITTING.
```

However what bothers me is that it's not even possible to bind to a denied port *within* a container without exposing the port:

```
$ podman run docker.io/library/alpine nc -lp 20202
nc: bind: Operation not permitted
```

Is this a bug? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: If the software inside the container supports _socket activation_, you have some more alternatives. I did an [experiment](https://github.com/eriksjolund/podman-nginx-socket-activation/tree/main/examples/example3) with a _systemd system service_ with the systemd directive `User=` and rootless Podman and socket-activated nginx. `ip_unprivileged_port_start` can be set to a high number. Status: experimental

Comment: Maybe it depends on your network mode. If you're using host mode network, then you always bind on the host network.

Comment: It seems that those BPF filters systemd employs don't care where a bind-syscall comes from or goes to; if it matches the SocketBindDeny rules, it will be denied. From that standpoint, a bind call within a container is no different from one outside a container regardless of network mode.